Как сделать регулировку высоты qtextedit вверх
Я пишу свой мессенджер, и мне нужно сделать строку для печати сообщений. Поведение я хочу как в телеграмме/дискорде. Там при печате текста виджет увеличивается вверх до определенного размера. Я попытался сделать тоже самое задав минимальную высоту на 30, а максимальную на 150, по итогу виджет просто растянуло на пикселей 100
Появилось 2 вопроса:

Как сделать так, чтобы изначально виджет был 30 пикселей, и если места не хватает - увеличивался?
Как сделать так, чтобы он увеличивался вверх?

То как у меня:

В дискорде:


Упомянутая вами минимальная и максимальная высота работает только в контейнерах компоновки и задаёт ограничения размера виджета при изменении размера окна. Для решения вашей задачи в Qt нет готовых инструментов, вам придётся самостоятельно ловить событие ввода, определять количество строк и в зависимости от этого регулировать положение и размер виджета.
